# Can't send e-mail with attachement

Tags: python, email

According to [this article (section #V To send an email with attachment)](http://naelshiab.com/tutorial-send-email-python/), I should be able to send an e-mail with attachement. However, I get the error,

```
 line 6, in <module>
  from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
  ImportError: No module named 'email.MIMEMultipart'
```

Any idea, how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial you're reading is for Python 2.x. In Python 3.x (which I assume is what you're using), I think you want this:

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
```

See also [the email.mime documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/email.mime.html).